# How to instantiate via dependency injection with autofac

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I currently has this line of code that works using .net's DI.

```
services.AddSingleton<IAmazonS3>(client => new AmazonS3Client(id, secret, region));
```

I would like to convert this to use autofac's. May I ask how do I do the same thing?

I tried the code below but unfortunately my amazons3client doesn't get instantiated with the specified parameters.

```
builder.RegisterType<AmazonS3Client>()
    .As<IAmazonS3>()               
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string),
            (pi, ctx) => id))
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string),
            (pi, ctx) => secret))
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string),
            (pi, ctx) => region))
    .SingleInstance();
```

I also tried but that didn't work either unfortunately, when i set a breakpoint on the return statement, it doesn't get hit.

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
        {
            return new AmazonS3Client(id, secret, region);
        });
```

My application usage

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
{

}
```

Comment: In addition to the given answer, I'm pretty sure that you are registering your dependency incorrectly. The line `.As<IAmazonS3>(client  => new AmazonS3Client())` should be changed to `.As<IAmazonS3>()`

Comment: @Greg good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
{

}
```

You are not resolving that class from the DI container, so it creates new instance.

You need to do sth like:

`var client = container.Resolve<IAmazonS3Client>();`

or inject it to constructor.

Your code is not being hit, because that return from DI will get called on Resolve.

Please take a look at this page for more options. Resolving of dependencies is very dependent on your platform, codebase and practices used in the codebase.

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me deeply understand where I went wrong